# What does this RegExp pattern /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/ mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex

```
/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/
```

pattern is intended to match a valid password.

I've searched the answer on regexper.com, here is the [link](https://regexper.com/#(%3F%3D.*%5Cd)(%3F%3D.*%5Ba-z%5D)(%3F%3D.*%5BA-Z%5D).%7B6%2C%7D).

I know the meaning of the contents in each parenthesis, but I don't know why here are there parentheses and how they work together..

Comment: https://www.debuggex.com/r/Xy7oLbfnQqp7Hm3H

Answer (score 4):

The pattern  `(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}` asserts

- 6 or more characters
- a digit
- a lower-case letter
- an upper-case letter

That's it.

Explanation of the moving parts:

- `(?=.*\d)` checks if a digit exists using a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).
- `(?=.*[a-z])` checks in the same fashing to see if a lowercase letter exists.
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` .. and an uppercase letter exists as well.
- `.{6,}` The 6+ quantifier is obvious.

The beauty of using a lookahead here is it makes it easy to (spot and) maintain the password rules.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: The question is asking how the groups work together to give the desired output. The OP knows how the regex behaves but doesn't know why. This answer doesn't even begin to explain it. It's only telling them what they already know.

Answer (score 1):

`(?=.*\d)` This is a positive lookahead to see if a digit exists

`(?=.*[a-z])` This is a positive lookahead to see if a lowercase letter exists

`(?=.*[A-Z])` This is a positive lookahead to see if an uppercase letter exists

`.{6,}` This matches for 6 or more of any character

So overall, it expects a string of 6 or more characters that contains at least one number, one lowercase letter, and one uppercase letter.